# ERROR: for app Cannot start service app: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up` I am getting an error:

```
Starting XXXX_app_1 ... 
Starting XXXX_app_1
xxxxx_memcached_1 is up-to-date
xxxxx_daemon_1 is up-to-date
Starting XXXX_db_1 ... 
Starting elasticsearch ... 
Starting XXXX_db_1
xxxxx_redis_1 is up-to-date
Starting XXXX_app_1 ... error

ERROR: for XXXXX_app_1  Cannot start service app: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting contaStarting elasticsearch ... done
xxxxx_kibana_1 is up-to-date

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        HOST_IP: "${HOST_IP}"
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_APP_PORT}:80"
      - "${DOCKER_APPS_PORT}:443"
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
      - REDIS_SAVE_PATH=tcp://redis:6379
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:delegated
    working_dir: /var/www/html
 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70847658/edit# daemon:
    image: newrelic/php-daemon
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.3
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5.12
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: ****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
    volumes:
      - ./:/tmp/tmp
      - ./mysql-data/:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_DB_PORT}:3306"
    working_dir: /var/lib/mysql
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:6.7.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "${ES_PORT}:9200"
  kibana:
    image: kibana:6.7.2
    ports:
      - "${KIBANA_PORT}:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
volumes:
  XXXX_data:
    driver: "local"
  esdata1:
    driver: "local"
```

The image is based on a custom Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM custom/app:latest


ADD docker/apache-php/conf/custom.apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
ADD docker/apache-php/conf/custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/cli/conf.d/
ADD docker/apache-php/conf/custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/apache/conf.d/
ADD docker/apache-php/conf/custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

ARG HOST_IP=host.docker.internal

RUN     pecl install xdebug-2.7.0beta1 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_host=$HOST_IP" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "opcache.enable=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: That error message could literally mean what it says: an image built `FROM scratch` won't have `/bin/sh` or anything else that you don't explicitly `COPY` in.  Without seeing any code it's very hard to tell, though.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including the `docker-compose.yml` file and the relevant image's Dockerfile?

Comment: same was working before but now it is crashing

Comment: What is the `custom/app` image; what is its `CMD` (and/or `ENTRYPOINT`)?  From what it looks like in the diagnostics the image build seems to be running, which does imply there is a shell (the `RUN` command would use it).  Trimming down the `docker-compose.yml` to not include unnecessary details would help narrow down where the problem is (do you have the same problem without the MySQL or Elasticsearch containers, for example?).

Comment: yes, same issue if i remove them